# Fading Between Background Images

Tags: jquery

Hóla everyone...

So, I've created a jQuery function that is called on a click event, like so...

```
function biocontent(){
  var first = $(this).data('first'),
      last = $(this).data('last'),
      bio = $(this).data('bio'),
      img = $(this).data('image');
  $('#background').css('background-image','url('+img+')');
  $('#about-content article').html(bio);
  $('#first-name').html(first);
  $('#last-name').html(last);
}
```

The click event is like so...

```
$('.item').click(biocontent);
```

What I need is for the current background image of `#background` to fade out on the click and for the new one that is called in `$('#background').css('background-image','url('+img+')');` to be faded in. Anyway I could do that?

EDIT - HERE AS REQUESTED IS ALL THE HTML

```
<section id="about">

<div id="background"></div><!-- / #background -->

<div class="content-container"> 

<h2 class="title"><span>About</span> the Film</h2><!-- / .title -->

<nav id="about-nav">

<a href="#" class="about" data-about="Wintons Motion Pictures brings you a new, hard-hitting documentary film by Jesse Winton. TARGETED will be examining one of the key issues of the day, gun control, and will take you on a fast-paced journey, following 19 year-old director Jesse Winton as he travels across the world, and goes back to the historical roots of the gun-control agenda, exposing it, and bringing out the dark truth behind gun control. TARGETED will creatively answer the increasingly tough questions regarding the issue, as well as giving us a plan that will help to mobilize freedom-loving Americans to defend the rights and liberties that have been granted to us. Coming 2014." data-image="../img/about-background.jpg">Synopsis</a>

<h5 class="crew-title">Crew</h5><!-- / .crew-title -->
<ul id="crew-list">

  <li class="jesse" data-first="Jesse" data-last="Winton" data-bio="JESSE WINTON (Director/Writer) began making documentaries in 2010, and co-directed the award-winning 2011 film RESCUED: THE HEART OF ADOPTION AND CARING FOR ORPHANS. He is a partner in Wintons Motion Pictures, the production company behind Targeted, whose activities encompass feature film development and production. Jesse has spent years studying the work of his film hero, Steven Spielberg, learning the art of visual storytelling and screenwriting. Targeted is his second feature-length documentary." data-image="../img/crew/jesse-winton-background.jpg">
    <a href="#">Jesse Winton</a>
  </li>

  <li class="randy" data-first="Randy" data-last="Winton" data-bio="RANDY WINTON (Producer/Executive Producer) began producing professionaly in 2010, starting with the award-winning documentary Rescued: The Heart of Adoption & Caring for Orphans. Mr. Winton is a partner in Wintons Motion Pictures, the production company behind Targeted, whose activities encompass feature film development and production. Randy spent years as a small business owner before beginning to produce feature films." data-image="../img/about-background.jpg">
    <a href="#">Randy Winton</a>
  </li>

  <li class="matt" data-first="Matt" data-last="Blick" data-bio="MATT BLICK is an awesome person when you pretend he doesn't exist." data-image="../img/crew/matt-blick-background.jpg">
    <a href="#">Matt Blick</a>
  </li>

</ul><!-- / #crew-list -->
</nav><!-- / #abou-nav -->

<div class="top-mask"></div><!-- / .top-mask -->

<article id="about-content" class="content">

<h4 id="first-name"></h4><!-- / .first-name -->
<h3 id="last-name"></h3><!-- / .last-name -->

<article> 
</article>   

</article><!-- / #about-content -->

<div class="bottom-mask"></div><!-- / .bottom-mask -->

</div><!-- / .content-container -->

</section><!-- / #about -->
```

Thanks all!

Comment: please provide the html too

Comment: @AnoopJoshi `<section id="about">

  <div id="background"></div>

 
</section>` Here's the basics.

Comment: provide your entire html.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi just included

Comment: better to do `$('.item').click(function(){ biocontent() });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can animate background transitions in many browsers using CSS. Check out this fiddle I made for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/npVa8/

The key property here is

```
[browser-prefix]-transition: background-image 1s linear;
```

If compatibility is of greatest importance, however, this is not the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. Very familiar with CSS transitions, but I actually need it to happen in the context of a click function in jQuery.

Comment: Did you test the fiddle? That runs on click. I suppose you can set all necessary `transition` CSS attributes in the same function if you want, but I can't think of a good reason why you would.